# Where do I have to add license for core-plot?

Tags: core-plot

I would like to use core-plot library for an app. But before I'm starting im confused where to put the license. In the App or on a website? 
What should be included for the BSD license ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't include a license for a 3rd party library. It's already included by the library developer. What you sometimes have to add is an attribution (depending on the license). That means you have to list the developer's name and maybe a link to the library home page in your docs, about box or a prominent readme file. From what I remember the BSD license doesn't require attribution, so just include the lib and your done.

However, it's considered a nice move to still give some attribution to the dev, regardless of whether the license requires it or not, as this shows your appreciation of the work done and gives the dev some reputation (which is often the only payment for their work).